# Conan giving me error no such file or directory: '/.conan/conan.conf'

Tags: python, conan

I'm running the following connan command

```
conan user -p AXXXXXXX -r TTT XXXXX
```

For sure I know I have conan install as doing this: `conan --version` return `Conan version 1.21.1`
But I'm getting this error

```
12:01:14 + conan user -p **** -r TTT ****
12:01:14 Traceback (most recent call last):
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/bin/conan", line 11, in <module>
12:01:14     load_entry_point('conan==1.27.0', 'console_scripts', 'conan')()
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/conan.py", line 7, in run
12:01:14     main(sys.argv[1:])
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/client/command.py", line 2184, in main
12:01:14     conan_api, _, _ = Conan.factory()
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/client/conan_api.py", line 224, in factory
12:01:14     return cls(), None, None
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/client/conan_api.py", line 236, in __init__
12:01:14     migrator = ClientMigrator(self.cache_folder, Version(client_version), self.out)
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/client/migrations.py", line 27, in __init__
12:01:14     self.cache = ClientCache(cache_folder, out)
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/client/cache/cache.py", line 78, in __init__
12:01:14     self._store_folder = self.config.storage_path or self.cache_folder
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/client/cache/cache.py", line 150, in config
12:01:14     self.initialize_config()
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/client/cache/cache.py", line 240, in initialize_config
12:01:14     save(self.conan_conf_path, normalize(get_default_client_conf()))
12:01:14   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conans/util/files.py", line 194, in save
12:01:14     with open(path, "wb") as handle:
12:01:14 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/.conan/conan.conf'
```

Comment: Seems to be expecting a configuration file that you don't have.

Comment: Did you mean for that to be `~/.conan/conan.conf` (note the leading `~`)?

Comment: I have a `~/.conan/conan.conf` file, but not the one in the error: `/.conan/conan.conf`
So not sure why isn't taking the `~`

Comment: It seems be a permission error, you can't write on root level of your system. Try adding a custom conan folder. Set [CONAN_USER_HOME](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-user-home) to another valid directory.